# Google Analytics event tracking in Joomla with email cloaking on - any solutions?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, joomla, dom-events

Joomla's lovely email cloaking feature hides email addresses in bits of Javascript - which is nice, but has the side effect of breaking the onclick event tracking that you need to track someone clicking on a `mailto:` link in Google Analytics.

Does anyone know of a cunning way of tracking the mailto in Joomla? (I've got a not so cunning way to do it: turn off email cloaking, but I'd rather not do that)

Answer (score 0):

Sure there's a much better way. Use one of any number of form extensions and use forms instead of mailto links. Turning off the cloaking is just asking for everyone's email to be spammed in to oblivion and you can set up goals to track your submitted forms. It will also save you headaches if you ask your visitors for the info you would need to collect from them to reply to their inquiry as well.

Comment: Thanks Brent, we are using forms, but our experience is that our forms typically get emails from spammy seo firms offering to help us with online marketing :( whereas real customers often use the email address.